# pkg-config --cflags -- rdkafka "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH% error in VS code while debugging on Windows OS

Tags: windows, debugging, apache-kafka, librdkafka

Am facing this issue while **debugging** code in VS code on **windows OS**.
The code executes with no error but debugging isn't happening.

```
pkg-config --cflags  -- rdkafka
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Comment: You are getting an error, though. The executable is not on your PATH

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved.
In VS code debugger launch.json buildflag was set which caused issue..
pkg-config was in my PATH

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, can you expand on how you fixed it?